# Matrix word problem

Tags: matrices, word-problem

I have been trying to find the answer to this question or for something similar but I cannot find anything on this. Also, I tried looking in the textbook of mymathlab and can't find the problem like it in there either.

I just think I am not setting the problem up correctly.

Here is the statement: `Find the product of the sum of A and B and the difference between C and D`

I think it's $(A)(B)-(B)(A).$ But obviously, that is incorrect.

Here are the matrices:

$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right],\quad B=\left[\begin{matrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{matrix}\right],\quad
C=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{matrix}\right],\quad
D=\left[\begin{matrix}0&-1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find $(A+B)(C-D)$

Sum of $A$ and $B$ $$A+B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now difference of $C$ and $D$
$$C-D\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Now you need to find $$(A+B)(C-D)=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$(A+B)(C-D)=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$